# Standard fields in Custom Object

Tags: salesforce-id, custom-object, standard-objects

How many Standard fields do we have for a custom object ?

Is RecordId is also a standard field for the object?
Please help

Comment: You can also look at the salesforce.schema in the Force.com IDE to see all fields, including the standard fields

Answer (score 4):

The are [System fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm#topic-title) on most objects:

> Id 
> IsDeleted 
> **Audit Fields**: 
> CreatedById 
> CreatedDate 
> LastModifiedById
>   LastModifiedDate
>  SystemModstamp

Here you will find all standard salesforce objects:

[Standard Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)

Each object is linked to the detail page where all of standard fields of the standard object stands.

For example [Account](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> **Fields:** 
> AccountNumber
>  AccountSource
>  .. 
> Name 
> OwnerId

and so on.